# Angular Simple Table Filter Search Bar

Tags: angular

I am pulling an array of data from database and displaying it with a simple table.What i am trying to do is adding a Simple Table Filter Search Bar feature to this table.For example filter it by .name property.In this case courseData is the array.

```
<table  style="border-spacing: 5rem">
      <tr >
          <td style="font-size: 20px;">CRN</td>
          <pre> </pre>
          <td style = "font-size: 20px;" >Name</td>
          <pre> </pre>
          <td style ="font-size: 20px;" >Lecturer</td>
          <pre> </pre>
          <td style = "font-size: 20px;" >Level</td>
          <pre> </pre>
          <td style = "font-size: 20px;" >Days</td>
          <pre> </pre>
          <td style = "font-size: 20px;" >Time</td>



          </tr>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let data of courseData">
      <tr>
        <td style="text-decoration: underline;" (click)="crnClicked(data.crn)">{{data.crn}}</td>
        <pre> </pre>
        <td *ngIf="data.specialapp !=1" >{{data.name}}</td>
        <td style="font-weight: bold;"*ngIf="data.specialapp==1" >{{data.name}}</td>
        <pre> </pre>
        <td>{{data.lecturer}}</td>
        <pre> </pre>
        <td>{{data.level}}</td>
        <pre> </pre>
        <td>{{data.days}}</td>
        <pre> </pre>
        <td>{{data.hours}}</td>


        <button *ngIf="data.specialapp!=1" ion-button small  round (click)="addCrn(data.crn)" color="primary" block>+</button>

        </tr>

    </ng-container>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Attempt to filter courseData via an event. Your sample does not contain any typescript so it's difficult to provide a clear example. Typically, assuming courseData is a property, you would have an event on action in your typescript similar to:

`clicked($event) {
   this.courseData = this.courseData.filter(x => 
     x.name.toLowerCase().indexOf($event.value.toLowerCase()) > -1));
}`

Any number of variations could exist depending on what you seek to do (on keyUp, click, etc). Note, the example above is case insensitive.